# Name of design pattern where type and instance classes are mirrored

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, database-design

I have used this design pattern in several entity-component designs. Now I want to introduce it to my team:

It concerns a type-of relationship, where the instance structure and the type structure are mirrored using a naming convention:

```
Vehicle -- typeof -->  VehicleType
```

Vehicle and VehicleType can then be specialized (using composition or inheritance), but each side must mirror the other in class/table structure (not fields or methods):

```
PassengerCompartment    PassengerCompartmentType
 Passengers               NumberOfSeats 

CargoCompartment        CargoCompartmentType
 CargoWeight              CargoCapacity
```

In this way, the programmer can deduce where relevant data is, without having to consult a diagram or documentation.

Does this pattern have a name?

Answer (score -1):

I suppose it is a prototype pattern with additional restrictions based on typing https://www.oodesign.com/prototype-pattern.html. Always assume your specific design guidelines won't fit exactly* with common place design patterns , at the end of the day the implementation of a design pattern only makes sense around the specific problem you are going to solve with said pattern.

Comment: Prototype seems more like cloning an existing instance. In my case I have a template (type) that the new instances are based on.

Comment: It's more like the Flyweight pattern.

Comment: The Flyweight patter is used to reuse/share objects where identity doesn't matter. The purpose is to limit the number of objects instantiated, and reuse where it makes sense.   https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/flyweight